# Angular 2 performance issue because of binding watch cost

Tags: performance, angular, binding

Official Angular 2 documentation supports binding (not one time binding) for all official code snippets. I have noticed that 90% of cases we don't need to watch values once rendered since we are sure it will never changed. this 90% of cases watchers are making longer cycles which makes user experience slower. Is there a way to make one time binding ? if it is possible why is it so unpopular and official documentation don't talk about it despite the big benefit regarding performance ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [`ChangeDetectionStrategy`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ChangeDetectionStrategy-enum.html)?

There are certainly ways to optimize the performance, but most of the examples never work with the apps of the such scale where those optimizations would be required.

I would recommend reading this great [blog post](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html) about change detection in Angular 2 to get a better picture.